# Is it possible to have a QListWidget select multiple setCurrentItems

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

In PyQt I can have QListWidget select an item programmatically using `QListWidget.setCurrentItem(item)`. And this, of course, will select an item for me inside my QListWidget.

However, I'm wondering if there exists a method like `setCurrentItems([item1, item2, item3])` where if I give a list, it will select all the items in QListWidget that match those items.

Right now my current implementation only allows me to select one item. In this case, the item 'data2'

```
index = ['data', 'data1', 'data2']
for i in index:
    matching_items = listWidget.findItems(i, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
    for item in matching_items:
        listWidget.setCurrentItem(item)
```

[image]

It would be cool if something like this could be done.

```
index = ['data', 'data1', 'data2']
for i in index:
    matching_items.append(listWidget.findItems(i, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly))
listWidget.setCurrentItems(matching_items)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need an item based approach. I test it tomorrow

Comment: do you want to select several items? a currentItem is a selected item, but not every selected item is a currentItem.

Comment: Oh! I see! yeah I want all items that are given in a list to be selected

Comment: @tisaconundrum what is `obj`?

Comment: My bad, obj was supposed to be listWidget

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`QListWidget` by default supports a single selection, you must change the selection mode with `setSelectionMode`, in your case:

```
listWidget.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.MultiSelection)
```

If you want a `QListWidgetItem` to be selected you must use `setSelected(True)`.

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    listWidget = QListWidget()

    listWidget.addItems(["data{}".format(i) for i in range(10)])

    listWidget.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.MultiSelection)
    index = ['data2', 'data3', 'data5']
    for i in index:
        matching_items = listWidget.findItems(i, Qt.MatchExactly)
        for item in matching_items:
            item.setSelected(True)

    listWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to eyllanesc's answer. You can also opt for:

```
listWidget.setSelectionMode(QtListWidget.ExtendedSelection)
```

This will let you hold the `Ctrl` key to toggle an item's selection on/off. In addition to that, you can also hold the `Shift` key to toggle the selection of all items between the current item and the clicked item.

If you only want the `Shift` key selection feature but not the `Ctrl` key selection toggle feature, you can use:

```
listWidget.setSelectionMode(QtListWidget.ExtendedSelection)
```